# How to add a item to player

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to add some custom ability to [this](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/kitbattle-advanced.2872/) plugin by using it own API. I have some trouble adding items to players when they got a kill. I have tried a lot of different methods to add potion to the killer by using .addItem(). There is no wiki for this plugin and on their page, there is some information about the API. Here is my code

```
public class ChemistryAbility extends Ability{
    
//Return name of ability
@Override
public String getName() {
    
    return "Chemistry";
}

//Get the data form config file. 
@Override
public void load(FileConfiguration file) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

//Get the activate Material
@Override
public Material getActivationMaterial() {
    return null;
}

//Get the activate projectile
@Override
public EntityType getActivationProjectile() {
    return null;
}

//Will this ability activate when player attack another player
@Override
public boolean isAttackActivated() {
    return true;
}

//Will this ability activate when player get attacked by another player
@Override
public boolean isAttackReceiveActivated() {
    return false;
}

//Will this ability activate when player get damage
@Override
public boolean isDamageActivated() {
    return false;
}

//Will this ability activate when player interact with another player
@Override
public boolean isEntityInteractionActivated() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean execute(final Player p, final PlayerData PD, final Event e) {
    
    ItemStack potion = new ItemStack(Material.SPLASH_POTION, 3);
    
    PotionMeta pmeta = (PotionMeta) potion.getItemMeta();
    
    pmeta.addCustomEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.HARM, 1, 2), true);
    
    potion.setItemMeta(pmeta);
    
    
    Player killer = p.getKiller();
    
    
    if (p.isDead()) {
        p.getKiller();
        
        if (p.getKiller() instanceof Player) {
            
            killer.getInventory().addItem(potion);
            
        }
        
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: What is your problem ? What is not working ?

Answer (score 1):

K, So i don't know that much about plugin dev, but here is my best shot with 15 min of research. Not sure about the API, but if u can implement this outside the event, try this

```
@EventHandler
public void onKill(PlayerDeathEvent e) {
  if (e.getEntity().getKiller() != null) { // to check if there was actually a killer
    Entity killer = e.getEntity.getKiller(); // stores killer instance
    if (killer.hasMetadata("Chemistry")) { // checks if has class
       killer.getInventory().addItem(new ItemStack(Material.BOOK));
    }
  }
}
```

i think. i honestly dont know

Comment: Thank you for answer this but the plugin won't execute if the code is not inside the execute function.

Answer (score 0):

Potions have always been a pain in Minecraft. Mojang changes how item data works.

I have some Deprecated code that I made. This should work for a few of the upcoming updates.

```
    public ItemStack getPotionItem(Color c, PotionEffectType type, PotionType pType, boolean splash, int time, int level) {
    Potion p = new Potion(pType);
    p.setSplash(splash);
    p.setType(pType);

    ItemStack pot = new ItemStack(Material.SPLASH_POTION);
    PotionMeta im = (PotionMeta) pot.getItemMeta();
    List<String> lores = new ArrayList<String>();
    lores.add(getLore());
    im.setDisplayName(getName());
    im.addCustomEffect(new PotionEffect(type, time, level - 1), true);
    
    im.setLore(lores);
    im.setColor(getColor());
    im.addItemFlags(ItemFlag.HIDE_POTION_EFFECTS);
    im.addItemFlags(ItemFlag.HIDE_ATTRIBUTES);
    pot.setItemMeta(im);
    p.apply(pot);
    return pot;
}
```